# Grommet TextArea exports multiline text as a single line in the image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas, html2canvas, grommet

I want to export Grommet `TextArea` as an image. The following code works if there is just a single line of text. But if I adjust the `TextArea` component in a way to make the text fill multiple lines, this won't be exported in the output image.

This is how it looks (1 - is the page which contains the multiline `TextArea` I want to export, 2 - the exported `TextArea`, containing just a single line of text)
[image]

Seems like I'm just missing something about HTML canvas. Or maybe there is some property in Grommet `TextArea` which helps with changing that behavior?

**App.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { TextArea } from "grommet";
import "./styles.css";
import { exportComponentAsPNG } from "react-component-export-image";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.textRef = React.createRef();

    this.state = { text: "" };
  }

  render() {
    const { text } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <TextArea
          ref={this.textRef}
          value={text}
          onChange={(event) => this.setState({ text: event.target.value })}
        />
        <button onClick={() => exportComponentAsPNG(this.textRef)}>
          Click
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**index.js:**

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**index.html:**

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue came out from `html2canvas` library, which is a core of `react-component-export-image`.
There are a couple of threads for this issue in the `html2canvas` community, including this one (the main one, I guess):
https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/2008

The best solution (which also helped in my case) is to use `contenteditable` div instead of `textarea` element

Answer (score 2):

I think that the issue lay in the way the image is being exported. I created a quick test using only 'textarea' of HTML instead of the Grommet TextArea component and the issue still occurs:
[image]

I've verified that the behavior you've described is the expected behavior from `react-component-export-image` package by running the HTML example on their demo app, and it seems that this is their core functionality behavior. You might want to [file an enhancement request](https://github.com/salman-monetate/react-component-export-image#readme) that asks to support multiline screenshots. Here is the screenshot example from running the HTML example on their demo app:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this! Maybe you know some another lib that has said functionality?